# Issue with debezium oracle connector

Tags: debezium

we are trying to use debezium kafka connect for data stream from oracle to postgress . we have configured kafka zookeeper debezium connect in docker. Its up and running, But while trying to connect to oracle using the json curl post we are getting this error

error_code":500,"message":"Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnector

Anyone can help on oracle - debezium connect - kafka stack??

Comment: Have you installed the connector? This message is saying that Kafka Connect cannot find it.

Comment: See https://rmoff.net/2020/06/19/how-to-install-connector-plugins-in-kafka-connect/

Comment: we have copied the instant client files
we are docker compose ...and all 3 instances .. zookeeper, kafka and kafka connect are up and running
we have given env path for instantclient in dockerfile were we copied 2 jar files ojdbc8.jar and xstream.jar to /kafka/libs

Comment: and we are able to see those files in the kafka connect docker container
but when we post json for registering an instance ..we are getting this error
error_code":500,"message":"Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnector

Comment: Right, so you've installed the instant client - but you've not installed the actual Debezium connector plugin. This doesn't ship with Kafka Connect - you need to install it. Check out the blog link that I posted.

Comment: will connect work without confluent ?.

Comment: You don't need Confluent Platform to run Debezium.

Comment: But we are facing error for oracle connector ... 3 docker instanced are up .. zookeeper, Kafka and debezium Kafka connect... but when we try to register the connector we are getting the below error

Comment: we are getting this error while registering the connector in post
{"error_code":500,"message":"Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnector, available c onnectors are: PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSi nkConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector', versi on='2.5.0', encodedVersion=2.5.0, type=sink, typeName='sink', location='file:/ka fka/libs/connect-file-2.5.0.jar'},